# how to delete cookies set from a site which viewed from a php script?

Tags: php, cookies

I wrote a php code that send some data via POST or GET to a site , 
that site set a cookie and session to my code, 
I need to delete the cookies set in the past request to start a new request. so the site needs to set a new cookie.

is that possible ?

thank you

Comment: Give us more information about how you send the data. Flat curl? Some class?

Comment: assume it is a simple get , for example grabbing http://site/?name=xxx

Comment: Generally you can control on your own whether or not you want to accept a cookie. However that depends a bit how you request the page (not only GET or POST but the actual code you use/write). As you have not shared your code the only answer that can be given is: **Yes**. Any more questions?

Comment: does it uses a file for storing cookies? like browsers?

Answer (score -1):

Yes u can delete cookie by setting past expiry date like below.

```
<?php
// set the expiration date to one hour ago
setcookie ("TestCookie", "", time() - 3600);
setcookie ("TestCookie", "", time() - 3600, "/~rasmus/", "example.com", 1);
?>
```

Comment: That does not delete a cookie. It sets only the cookie header(s) (server side) which is totally unrelated to the question - because the question is client-side.

Comment: Please refer "Example 2" section in below link "http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php" hope it helps

Comment: *"setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers."* - You should better read what you link.

Comment: `-1` This is what you do in the **server**. The question is specifically asking about a PHP script being used as the **client**.